# How to specify the Bluemix Docker container "size" through the CLI?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to create a Docker container from an image I already have on my Bluemix account with a "micro" size (256MB RAM/16GB storage).

A sample of the command I have so far is (with fake IP address):

```
cf ic run -p 123.123.123.123:80:8080 \
--expose=2003 \
-v graphite_volume:/opt/graphite/storage/whisper \
--name graphite \
registry.ng.bluemix.net/sitespeed/graphite
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to **set a size for this container in this command**, so it defaults to "Pico", which has too little RAM to be usable for my purposes. If I use the UI and set the size, I'm not sure how to forward ports (I think they are only exposed) and setting the volume fails to work (it gets set to "None").

Setting memory limit with `-m 256M` hasn't worked, as it still sets the size to Pico, with 64M. Is there a way to set the "size" for Docker containers through the Bluemix CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the CF CLI plugin for IBM Containers does not support this functionality yet.

You can still use the [ICE tool](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/container_cli_ov_ice.html) to start containers from the command line and set the memory explicitly.

```
usage: ice run [-h] [--name NAME] [--memory MEMORY] [--env ENV]
           [--publish PORT] [--volume VOL] [--bind APP] [--ssh SSHKEY]
           [--link LINK]
           IMAGE [CMD [CMD ...]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @james-thomas. That works if I don't forward any ports. However, forwarding ports throws the error "ice run: error: argument --publish/-p: invalid int value: '80:8080'". Do you know of a way to forward ports rather than just exposing them? I'd like :80 in the container exposed as :8080.

Comment: Nevermind, just exposing ports worked for my use case.